# Statements for role codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Sorry if my english is poor, Please help me.

I want to create a user, operator and admin. But I can only make admin and user.

How to add 1 more user to this code

```
if ($user['is_active'] == 1) {

    if (password_verify($password, $user['password'])) {
        $data = array(
            'username' => $user['username'],
            'role_id' => $user['role_id']
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        if ($user['role_id'] == 1) {
            redirect('admin');
        } else {
            redirect('user');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($user['is_active'] == 1) {

    if (password_verify($password, $user['password'])) {
        $data = array(
            'username' => $user['username'],
            'role_id' => $user['role_id']
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        if ($user['role_id'] == 1) {
            redirect('admin');
        } elseif ($user['role_id'] == 2) {
            redirect('operator');
        } else {
            redirect('user');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [switch statement](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_switch.asp).

```
switch($user['role_id']){
    case 1:
        redirect("admin");
        break;
    case 2:
        redirect("operator");
        break;
    default:
        redirect("user");
        break;
}
```